# Why does the E-Field not change given two parallel capacitors?

Tags: circuit-analysis, kirchhoffs-laws

I just cannot imagine, why connecting two voltage sources in parallel does not change the E-Field (strenghting it) and thus does not lead to higher voltage.

[image]

In this case charged plate capacitors are connected in parallel and we are assuming only small changes in time such that the capacitors do not discharge significantly.
I would assume, that the fact that there are now twice as many charges on one site, the E-Field would change (twice its absolute), resulting in a higher voltage.

But this does not happen. How can this be explained?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I would assume, that the fact that there are now twice as many charges on one site, the E-Field would change (twice its absolute), resulting in a higher voltage.

There are twice as many charges (assuming identical capacitors), but these are spread out over twice the area. Therefore, the E fields within the capacitors does not change.

Since the capacitors are not discharging, there is no current flowing through the wire. Therefore, by the microscopic version of Ohm's law \$\vec{E} = \rho\vec{J}\$ there is no E field within the wires (or resistor) either.

> What happens if they discharge?

If a capacitor is discharging through its leads, then by the microscopic version of Ohm's law, there is an E field within the conductors of the circuit proportional to the resistivity and current density within those conductors.

If there are two equal capacitors discharging at the same time, the discharge rate of each capacitor will be half the rate as would be the case if there were only one capacitor. Or, to put it another way, it will take twice as long for two capacitors to discharge to half their charge as it would take for one capacitor to discharge. So, the E field within the wires will be between two different values of strength for twice as long if we have two capacitors, than if we have one. But its initial value will be the same whether we have 1 or 2 capacitors.

Comment: What happens if they discharge?

Comment: then the voltages are still identical between the two capacitors, and this answer still applies. Whether or not there's E-field in the wires depends on your physical model of "wire". If you draw a schematic like you did, the physical model of a wire is an infinitesimal short, superconducting without current limit wire. So, no field exists in that model. In the updated answer, Math Keeps Me Busy explicitly addresses a more complex model than your drawing allows for: components and wires have > 0 sizes and resistivity.